# Replacing ceiling fan with standard light fixture

Tags: light

Ive replaced a ceiling fan with a standard light fixture in our living room. However the light turns on but the switch to the light doesnt work.

There is a red wire in the wall and in the ceiling which i assume allows the switch to control the light, but i dont know what to connect the red wire to in both the switch and in the ceiling. The black (hot) and white are connected properly and thus is getting power to the fixture. The red wire is currently disconnected on both ends.

Thanks in advance for any guidance on this.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes?

Comment: Did the switch on the wall (switches) control fan and light separately? Or do you have 2 switches that controlled the fixture from different sides/areas of the room?